# Qt Swipe-animation to other .ui file

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, animation

I'm working on an application with a login page and a registration page. All the widgets on the login form have been placed using the design tab in Qt creator.

How would I go about animating all widgets on the login at the same time to swipe off to the side and introduce the register page - stored in another ui file? I tried adding all widgets to a `QStackedWidget` and animate that - but every widget I add to it vanishes from the form.

I just can't seem to figure this out - any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried?

Comment: I've tried adding all the widgets to a QStackedWidget and swipe that off the screen by animating the "pos" property with a QPropertyAnimation. Anything I add to the stacked disappears off the form. I'm also not sure as to how I'm going to bring in the second .ui.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `QStackedWidget` just create the new widget on top of the previous and offscreen, and use the animation to slide it into place. You don't need to animate all widgets, just the container widget, the rest will move with it.

Or better off, if you are going to make animated GUI, go for a QML UI instead. It is much easier to work with.